# Corona - create regular display objects from sprite sheets?

Tags: image, lua, coronasdk, sprite-sheet

This is normal way of displaying an image:

```
local img = display.newImage("image.png");
```

But doesn't it save memory to put all your images in one large image and export from Zwoptex? There is documentation for creating animated sprites from sprite sheets, but what about just pulling a single image from a sprite sheet?

```
local zwoptexData = require "sheet1"
local data = zwoptexData.getSpriteSheetData()
//then what?
```

Comment: That command for loading images is getting old. The latest command is newImageRect because that supports dynamic image resolution. Doesn't change your question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands to make a static image from a tile sheet look like this:

```
local tileSheet = sprite.newSpriteSheet("tiles.png", 64, 64)
local tileSet = sprite.newSpriteSet(tileSheet, 1, 10)
local tile = sprite.newSprite(tileSet)
tile.currentFrame = 5
```

That assumes all the tiles on the sheet are 64x64 but you could easily adapt those commands to use your sprite sheet data. The important things to note are newSprite() and .currentFrame

EDIT: You commented that you can't figure out how to use sprite data with this, so the modified code is

```
local data = require("tiles.lua")
local tileSheet = sprite.newSpriteSheetFromData("tiles.png", data.getSpriteSheetData())
local tileSet = sprite.newSpriteSet(tileSheet, 1, 3)
local tile = sprite.newSprite(tileSet)
tile.currentFrame = 2
```

To learn how this works refer to
http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/sprite-sheets

Comment: That was just an example. In my code there are 10 frames, and I set the sprite to frame 5. Both those values will be different for you.

Comment: having a hard time getting this to work. I have a sprite data file called "sheet1.lua", and a sprite sheet called "sheet1.png" which contains 3 images. How do I get the 2nd image from the sprite sheet and display it as a display object?