# Creating an image from a sprite sheet using the original images file name

Tags: lua, sprite, coronasdk, sprite-sheet

Creating sprite sheets aka texture atlases rather than using many hundres of individual images is recommended everywhere. I have hundreds of images for a word learning game; but there are hundreds of words, no animation sequences. So having generated the data file and sprite sheet, i am looking for an example of how to create an image when needed from the original image file name (as stored in the sprite sheet data (lua code) file (both created with texture packer).

This much seems right:

```
local sprite = require("sprite")

local CN_70_tiles_corona = require("CN_70_tiles_corona")

local spriteDataCN = CN_70_tiles_corona.getSpriteSheetData()

local spriteSheet = sprite.newSpriteSheetFromData( "CN_70_tiles_corona.png", spriteDataCN )
```

before creating the sprite sheet, would create my image with something like this:

```
t1 =    display.newImage(cnTiles[tileNO])
```

where cnTiles[1], for examples, is a value placed in an array from a sqlite table such as "sit_word100.png".

there is now an entry in my generate lua file below the 'getSpritSheetData' function something like this:

```
{
  name = "sit_word100.png",
  spriteColorRect = { x = 0, y = 0, width = 69, height = 69 },
  textureRect = { x = 2, y = 2, width = 69, height = 69 },
  spriteSourceSize = { width = 69, height = 69 },
  spriteTrimmed = false,
  textureRotated = false
},
```

i can see that ALL my image file names are now stored in the data to provide a way to refer to my image within the sprite sheet, but since i do NOT want to use "sprite sets", i can't find an example of just getting the one image when in eed it.

I want something that allows me to refer to my now spritesheet-ified image using the original image name. is this possible? e.g.

```
t1 =    display.newImage(CN_70_tiles_corona.getSpriteSheetData(name = "sit_word100.png")
```

Comment: Update: i found an IOS / objective C Cocos2d answer at [link](http://allseeing-i.com/Performance-tips-for-Cocos2d-for-iPhone) that showed: `CCTexture2D *texture = 
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"myatlastexture.png"];
CCSprite *sprite = 
[CCSprite spriteWithTexture:texture rect:CGRectMake(0,0,32,32)];`  So i am looking for a Lua version. will check the docs wit this clue in mind.

Comment: This question also was ask here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655055/corona-create-regular-display-objects-from-sprite-sheets) but answered in temrs of a SpriteSet. Argh. don't want to create a one tile spriteset -- is that the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to create sheets with [TexturePacker](http://www.texturepacker.com) and use SpriteGrabber to take the sprites your need.

It's an awesome add-on to Corona-SDK which can be found here:

http://developer.anscamobile.com/code/spritegrabber-spritesheets-two-lines

Comment: Andreas: I love your Texturepacker -- that is why i have the spritesheets to work with.  i bought it and the physics editor too just for the good pricing for the combo. Fantastic and easy to use. Many easy options. I just needed some code sample in lua that pull sprites from the big sheet. SpriteGrabber is EXACTLY the solution!!@ thanks!

Comment: nice sprite grabber. @hangzhouharry you should accept the answer if it is useful.